# How to authenticate in a GraphQL playground

Tags: authentication, graphql, jwt, token, graphql-playground

I'm working for someone and writing GraphQL queries in GraphQL playground for them. I'm new to GraphQL and have just learned writing queries.

Suddenly they put authentication in GraphQL playground. And sent me a text which goes something like this.

> Hey Engineering,
>
> I have updated the code with authentication on the GraphQL Server.
>
> Kindly generate a valid JWT token to work on the system.
>
> JWT_SECRET=8yz5twkIonm3XPZZfNolpKl3z9FMdmpgXwo5a9fp6rD8IodRM8EPHAB6iHsc0fb

I have lost my access to playground because of that I can't continue my work. I contacted them to obtain a guide for authentication. But no use. And I don't know how to use that JWT Secret to get access.

Comment: Hopefully that is not a real secret. If it is the one you sent, it is worth you replying to the sender to say that you published it on the web, and they need to regenerate it.

Comment: I don't know enough to help completely, but you can [start here](https://jwt.io/). I think you can paste your secret into the generator, though you are likely to need to do more research to find out how to go from there.

Comment: @halfer : Yes..this is not the real secret that I've shared. I knew those secrets should not be reveled to the public.   well. Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate.